# Does SQL Server Compact support brackets?

Tags: ado.net, sql-server-ce

According to this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174147.aspx SQL Server Compact 4.0 doesn't support brackets. Looking at EF5 migration SQL commands (using `-verbose` in the package manager console) I get code like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [Products] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](4000),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Products] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
```

Am I missing something here? Perhaps ADO.NET has some special handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Compact supports brackets for identifiers, seems like a documentation issue.